# Rails form submitted with GET request does not place querystring parameters in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working from the RailsGuides Action View Form Helpers article, in the "1.1 A Generic Search Form" section, using this code:

```
<% form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

When submitting this form, the resulting URL is '/search
', not '/search?q=searchterm', as would be expected.

The RailsGuides article even goes on to say,

> Use "GET" as the method for search forms. This allows users to bookmark a specific search and get back to it. More generally Rails encourages you to use the right HTTP verb for an action.

However, it would be impossible to bookmark a specific search if the querystring parameter is not included in the URL. Why is this occurring, and what can be done about this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
`<%= form_with url: search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :q, "Search for: " %>
  <%= f.text_field :q %>
  <%= f.submit :Submit%>
 <% end %>`
```

form_with is an updated rails helper with rails 6

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. When submitting the form, the browser URL is still the search path without the querystring parameter.